# Tables have turned or Tables are turned?

Tags: differences, idioms

I often get confused while using this idiom. Can anyone give the use case for each of them? Or is that only one phrase is correct among them and the other one is wrong?

Comment: I've never heard of "the tables are turned", but Googling does suggest some use: I would say they mean the same thing but "tables have turned" is more common and makes more sense. Perhaps you may be thinking of "to turn the tables". Examples may be "ah, but Mr Bond, the tables have turned", or "Bond, you've got to turn the tables on Dr No".

Comment: So basically its OK to change the sentence of an idiom without loosing its meaning. I thought it was supposed to be used as defined.

Comment: ... (In response to your comment) **No**. Or rather, not in general. In her monumental work [Fixed Expressions and Idioms in English: A Corpus-Based Approach](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/fixed-expressions-and-idioms-in-english-9780198236146?cc=gb&lang=en&), Rosamund Moon spends a whole chapter looking at which FEIs exhibit variation, and how they may individually be varied. Thus, for example, 'fall in line' / 'fell in line' are fine whereas 'tumble in line' and 'line was fallen into by X' are not. Each FEI has to be examined carefully for allowable variations.

Comment: 'The tables are turned' is licensed by [Usingenglish.com](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/tables+are+turned.html) and the [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+the+tables). 'The tables have turned' is quite commonly seen on the internet; it involves using 'turn' in the middle voice (so 'How the tables have turned' = 'How the tables have been turned' and is equivalent to 'How the tables are [now] turned', _and **is used** as a variant_). Compare   'How are the mighty fallen!' //  'How the mighty have fallen!'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for your explanation and sharing your knowledge.